# Android communication from child thread to main thread

Tags: android

I have an android application with a main thread and a child thread. I need the child thread to send messages periodically to the main thread. The main thread in turn updates the UI. I have tried to do this process using a handler, obtainMessage() and sendMessage() etc but my application fails when the main thread updates the textView even though I print the message received to the log and it's perfectly fine.

So I tried another way of posting a runnable in the child thread to update the UI

**In the main thread:**

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    public TextView mMatchesText;
    public Handler mHandler;  
    private ServerConnection conn;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mMatchesText = (TextView) Example.this.findViewById(R.id.matches);
        mMatchesText.setText("Matches:\n");     /*this text appears when I run the app*/
        mHandler = new Handler();
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());

 public class SampleAuthListener implements AuthListener {

        public void onAuthSucceed() {
            Example.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        conn = new ServerConnection(mProfile.toString());
                    }
                });
        }
   }
```

**In the child thread (ServerConnection.java):**

```
/* constructor */
public ServerConnection()
{
    runner = new Thread(this);
    runner.start();
}


public void run()
{
    String fromServer;

    /** Establish connection to the server */

    /** Wait for messages from the server */
    while((fromServer = inFromServer.readLine()) != null)
    {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Log.e("MY APP", fromServer);
                mMatchesText.setText(fromServer); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The application again fails at line 56 which is **mMatchesText.setText(fromServer);** 
formServer is not null because I print it to the LogCat and it indeed contains the data sent by the server.

```
    11-24 08:02:49.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14571): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-24 08:02:49.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14571): java.lang.NullPointerException

    11-24 08:02:49.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14571): at com.facebook.android.ServerConnection$1.run(ServerConnection.java:56) <--this is mMatches..

    11-24 08:02:49.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14571): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

    11-24 08:02:49.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14571): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

    11-24 08:02:49.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14571): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

    11-24 08:02:49.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14571): at
```

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

Just in case it helps, the mMatchesText is declared in main.xml as follows:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/matches"
android:textColor="@drawable/black"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/Login"
android:text=""
/>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: seems like fromServer is null

Comment: Post the code where nMatchesText gets initialized

Answer (score 1):

`mMatchesText` is null when it is used here: `mMatchesText.setText(fromServer);`

Unless you show us your initialization of it, that's all we can help you.

Comment: mMatchesText is null. Please post more code where it is mentioned. You can declare it in XML, but you still need to initialize the mMatchesText variable somewhere in your Java.

Comment: I initialize the mMatchesText in the main thread. Also, to make sure it is not null, I write a test string and it does appear on the screen. However, in the child thread an error occurs even when I try to update the UI with a dummy string. Besides trying the mHandler.post in the child thread, I have tried defining a handleMessage() method in the main thread that receives messages from the child and updates the UI but that too fails. It is driving me crazy! I have added some more code to above. Please please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it, in all my apps.
Make a custom Runnable class like this

```
public abstract class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public Object data;
    public MyRunnable setData(Object data){
        this.data=data;
        return this;
    }
    public MyRunnable setData(Object... dataArr){
        data=dataArr;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it to send data to the Runnable

```
//this is you code from question, i modified the use of runnable and String fromServer
public void run()
{
    String fromServer;

    /** Establish connection to the server */

    /** Wait for messages from the server */
    while((fromServer = inFromServer.readLine()) != null)
    {
        mHandler.post(new MyRunnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //here variable fromServer is not available inside the Runnable object
                String fromServerCpy=(String)data;//getting the fromServer sent to MyRunnable
                Log.e("MY APP", fromServerCpy);
                mMatchesText.setText(fromServerCpy); 
            }
        }.setData(fromServer));// !!! sending fromServer to MyRunnable data variable
    }
}
```